# How to bind wpf ComboBox to change the Language withougt writting into the xaml.cs?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have wpf combobox as below.

```
<ComboBox  Margin="71.421,3.417,-0.002,2.998" Width="167.244" Height="20" ToolTip="Change language settings" Padding="4,1,4,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="English" IsSelected="True"   />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="中文" />
</ComboBox>
```

And , I have this culture class below.

```
public class SpecificCultures
    {
        public static readonly string AR_SA = "ar-SA";
        public static readonly string BG_BG = "bg-BG";
        public static readonly string CA_ES = "ca-ES";
        public static readonly string ZH_TW = "zh-TW";
        public static readonly string CS_CZ = "cs-CZ";
        public static readonly string DA_DK = "da-DK";
        public static readonly string DE_DE = "de-DE";
        public static readonly string EL_GR = "el-GR";
        public static readonly string EN_US = "en-US";
        public static readonly string FI_FI = "fi-FI";
        public static readonly string FR_FR = "fr-FR";
        public static readonly string HE_IL = "he-IL";
        public static readonly string HU_HU = "hu-HU";
        public static readonly string IS_IS = "is-IS";
        public static readonly string IT_IT = "it-IT";
        public static readonly string JA_JP = "ja-JP";
        public static readonly string KO_KR = "ko-KR";
        public static readonly string NL_NL = "nl-NL";
        public static readonly string NB_NO = "nb-NO";
        public static readonly string PL_PL = "pl-PL";
        public static readonly string PT_BR = "pt-BR";
        public static readonly string RO_RO = "ro-RO";
        public static readonly string RU_RU = "ru-RU";
        public static readonly string HR_HR = "hr-HR";
        public static readonly string SK_SK = "sk-SK";
        public static readonly string SQ_AL = "sq-AL";
        public static readonly string SV_SE = "sv-SE";
        public static readonly string TH_TH = "th-TH";
        public static readonly string TR_TR = "tr-TR";
        public static readonly string UR_PK = "ur-PK";
        public static readonly string ID_ID = "id-ID";
        public static readonly string UK_UA = "uk-UA";
        public static readonly string BE_BY = "be-BY";
        public static readonly string SL_SI = "sl-SI";
        public static readonly string ET_EE = "et-EE";
        public static readonly string LV_LV = "lv-LV";
        public static readonly string LT_LT = "lt-LT";
        public static readonly string FA_IR = "fa-IR";
        public static readonly string VI_VN = "vi-VN";
        public static readonly string HY_AM = "hy-AM";
        public static readonly string AZ_LATN_AZ = "az-Latn-AZ";
        public static readonly string EU_ES = "eu-ES";
        public static readonly string MK_MK = "mk-MK";
        public static readonly string AF_ZA = "af-ZA";
        public static readonly string KA_GE = "ka-GE";
        public static readonly string FO_FO = "fo-FO";
        public static readonly string HI_IN = "hi-IN";
        public static readonly string MS_MY = "ms-MY";
        public static readonly string KK_KZ = "kk-KZ";
        public static readonly string KY_KG = "ky-KG";
        public static readonly string SW_KE = "sw-KE";
        public static readonly string UZ_LATN_UZ = "uz-Latn-UZ";
        public static readonly string TT_RU = "tt-RU";
        public static readonly string PA_IN = "pa-IN";
        public static readonly string GU_IN = "gu-IN";
        public static readonly string TA_IN = "ta-IN";
        public static readonly string TE_IN = "te-IN";
        public static readonly string KN_IN = "kn-IN";
        public static readonly string MR_IN = "mr-IN";
        public static readonly string SA_IN = "sa-IN";
        public static readonly string MN_MN = "mn-MN";
        public static readonly string GL_ES = "gl-ES";
        public static readonly string KOK_IN = "kok-IN";
        public static readonly string SYR_SY = "syr-SY";
        public static readonly string DV_MV = "dv-MV";
        public static readonly string AR_IQ = "ar-IQ";
        public static readonly string ZH_CN = "zh-CN";
        public static readonly string DE_CH = "de-CH";
        public static readonly string EN_GB = "en-GB";
        public static readonly string ES_MX = "es-MX";
        public static readonly string FR_BE = "fr-BE";
        public static readonly string IT_CH = "it-CH";
        public static readonly string NL_BE = "nl-BE";
        public static readonly string NN_NO = "nn-NO";
        public static readonly string PT_PT = "pt-PT";
        public static readonly string SR_LATN_CS = "sr-Latn-CS";
        public static readonly string SV_FI = "sv-FI";
        public static readonly string AZ_CYRL_AZ = "az-Cyrl-AZ";
        public static readonly string MS_BN = "ms-BN";
        public static readonly string UZ_CYRL_UZ = "uz-Cyrl-UZ";
        public static readonly string AR_EG = "ar-EG";
        public static readonly string ZH_HK = "zh-HK";
        public static readonly string DE_AT = "de-AT";
        public static readonly string EN_AU = "en-AU";
        public static readonly string ES_ES = "es-ES";
        public static readonly string FR_CA = "fr-CA";
        public static readonly string SR_CYRL_CS = "sr-Cyrl-CS";
        public static readonly string AR_LY = "ar-LY";
        public static readonly string ZH_SG = "zh-SG";
        public static readonly string DE_LU = "de-LU";
        public static readonly string EN_CA = "en-CA";
        public static readonly string ES_GT = "es-GT";
        public static readonly string FR_CH = "fr-CH";
        public static readonly string AR_DZ = "ar-DZ";
        public static readonly string ZH_MO = "zh-MO";
        public static readonly string DE_LI = "de-LI";
        public static readonly string EN_NZ = "en-NZ";
        public static readonly string ES_CR = "es-CR";
        public static readonly string FR_LU = "fr-LU";
        public static readonly string AR_MA = "ar-MA";
        public static readonly string EN_IE = "en-IE";
        public static readonly string ES_PA = "es-PA";
        public static readonly string FR_MC = "fr-MC";
        public static readonly string AR_TN = "ar-TN";
        public static readonly string EN_ZA = "en-ZA";
        public static readonly string ES_DO = "es-DO";
        public static readonly string AR_OM = "ar-OM";
        public static readonly string EN_JM = "en-JM";
        public static readonly string ES_VE = "es-VE";
        public static readonly string AR_YE = "ar-YE";
        public static readonly string EN_029 = "en-029";
        public static readonly string ES_CO = "es-CO";
        public static readonly string AR_SY = "ar-SY";
        public static readonly string EN_BZ = "en-BZ";
        public static readonly string ES_PE = "es-PE";
        public static readonly string AR_JO = "ar-JO";
        public static readonly string EN_TT = "en-TT";
        public static readonly string ES_AR = "es-AR";
        public static readonly string AR_LB = "ar-LB";
        public static readonly string EN_ZW = "en-ZW";
        public static readonly string ES_EC = "es-EC";
        public static readonly string AR_KW = "ar-KW";
        public static readonly string EN_PH = "en-PH";
        public static readonly string ES_CL = "es-CL";
        public static readonly string AR_AE = "ar-AE";
        public static readonly string ES_UY = "es-UY";
        public static readonly string AR_BH = "ar-BH";
        public static readonly string ES_PY = "es-PY";
        public static readonly string AR_QA = "ar-QA";
        public static readonly string ES_BO = "es-BO";
        public static readonly string ES_SV = "es-SV";
        public static readonly string ES_HN = "es-HN";
        public static readonly string ES_NI = "es-NI";
        public static readonly string ES_PR = "es-PR";
        public static readonly string SMA_NO = "sma-NO";
        public static readonly string SR_CYRL_BA = "sr-Cyrl-BA";
        public static readonly string ZU_ZA = "zu-ZA";
        public static readonly string XH_ZA = "xh-ZA";
        public static readonly string FY_NL = "fy-NL";
        public static readonly string TN_ZA = "tn-ZA";
        public static readonly string SE_SE = "se-SE";
        public static readonly string SMA_SE = "sma-SE";
        public static readonly string HR_BA = "hr-BA";
        public static readonly string SMN_FI = "smn-FI";
        public static readonly string QUZ_PE = "quz-PE";
        public static readonly string SE_FI = "se-FI";
        public static readonly string SMS_FI = "sms-FI";
        public static readonly string CY_GB = "cy-GB";
        public static readonly string BS_LATN_BA = "bs-Latn-BA";
        public static readonly string BS_CYRL_BA = "bs-Cyrl-BA";
        public static readonly string FIL_PH = "fil-PH";
        public static readonly string SMJ_NO = "smj-NO";
        public static readonly string ARN_CL = "arn-CL";
        public static readonly string IU_LATN_CA = "iu-Latn-CA";
        public static readonly string MI_NZ = "mi-NZ";
        public static readonly string QUZ_EC = "quz-EC";
        public static readonly string GA_IE = "ga-IE";
        public static readonly string SR_LATN_BA = "sr-Latn-BA";
        public static readonly string MOH_CA = "moh-CA";
        public static readonly string SMJ_SE = "smj-SE";
        public static readonly string LB_LU = "lb-LU";
        public static readonly string NS_ZA = "ns-ZA";
        public static readonly string QUZ_BO = "quz-BO";
        public static readonly string SE_NO = "se-NO";
        public static readonly string MT_MT = "mt-MT";
        public static readonly string RM_CH = "rm-CH";

    }
```

In ViewModel.cs,

if the combbox selection is changed,

I need to call function to save the culture that the user selected.

Eg.

```
 SaveCuluterID(string culutredID)
{
   // process here to change language of the application, this is already done and working. 
}
```

if the user select english, culturedID should be SpecificCultures.EN_US. If it's chinese, should be
SpecificCultures.ZH_CN. It's working if I write into the xaml.cs. But, I need to do this logic in the ViewModel.cs as our workflow needs to be all about binding.Whatever the user select, I need to change it into CultureID. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest setting each ComboBoxItem's "Tag" property to the culture you want, or the string, and then setting the SelectedValuePath to point to "Tag" so that it will bind into the property you want.

Here's a good example/explanation:
http://johnpapa.net/binding-to-silverlight-combobox-and-using-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath-and-displaymemberpath

Answer (score 0):

you can bind Selected item to property declared in viewmodel

```
SelectedItem={Binding SelectedCulture}
```